# Statechart definition of two "parallel" processes

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to define two independent but related processes, criminal career and crime enforcement (imprisonment). Here is a diagram:

[image]

1. Crimes will be committed only if an agent has already started his criminal career through an internal transition. Desistance (to move away from crime) is a final state that can happen while an agent is imprisoned (that's why I define this problem as two independent processes).
2. When a crime occurs (internal transition `commitCrime`) the variable `committedCrime` is set to `true`. The `commitCrime` transition has as a guard `this.ImprisonmentStateChart.isStateActive(Free)`, so an agent cannot commit crimes if he is imprisoned.
3. Every time a crime is committed, a condition transition is assessed from state Free: `this.committedCrime == true`. Once in prison, an agent will be eventually released.

My problem is that the `commitCrime` transition is not restarted after coming back to the Free state. The idea would be to restart the `commitCrime` transition after `releaseFromPrison` is triggered, but I haven't found how to do it with Anylogic 7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to remove guard and wrap the action in if statement:

```
if ( ImprisonmentStateChart.isStateActive(Free) )
     committedCrime == true;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gosha. The problem with that solution is that the committedCrime rate transition is not restarted when being released from prison, but it comes from the last time being *free*.

Comment: @sdaza, then consider such solution: put reference parameter to parameter at Rate property of transition. Restore guard: `ImprisonmentStateChart.isStateActive( Free )`. Then, call `set_parameterName( 3 )` in On entry action of Free state, and `set_parameterName( 4 )` — in Imprisoned state. Each entering in Free state restarts rate transition, while call in Imprisoned state just changes the value to trigger restart on return to Free state (so only 3 matters, you can put any number above 0 instead of 4).